# Changing an already drawn rectangle's color?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
    pygame.draw.rect(display, black, [50,leady,15,15])
```

Is it possible to edit an already drawn rectangle? For example, when I press right, I want this rectangle to turn yellow. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to change the color of something that has already been blitted. However, it is possible to re-blit it with a new color. You'll want something like this:

```
rectColor = black
while True:
    display.fill(white)

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[k_right]:
        rectColor = yellow

    pygame.draw.rect(display, rectColor, [50,leady,15,15])

    #draw everything else

    pygame.display.update()
```